# Not able to send Parse push on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have integrated the push notifications by Parse.
The notifications looks properly integrated as when I send them from the web end, I am able to receive them.

Now when I send the same push from Android nothing happens, here is a small code for the same:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setMessage("Test");
        push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback(){
            public void done(ParseException pe){
                Log.i(pe==null?"No exception":"Exception");
            }
        });
```

Since I am able to receive push from web it's confirmed they are well integrated.

Then what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using channels to send your push notifications, you just forgot to set the channel for your push notification. You just need to add:

```
push.setChannel(YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME);
```

Comment: If I am setting that will that be a broadcast ? I did tested initially with channel only, but didn't worked out.